# Error converir NSData en NSString

Tags: swift, swift2, casting, nsdata

Tengo el siguiente código para convertir el body de una petición post en un string

```
let body: NSData = self.createBodyWithParameters(paramString, filePathKey: "image_name", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary, nameParam: "dparam_string_post")
let bodyString: String = NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
```

Me da error en la segunda linea:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Y la variable tiene contenido, he realizado un print y me ha mostrado el contenido

**EDITADO**
Tambien he probado con:

```
let cadena = String(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Pero me retorna `nil`

Answer (score 2):

Hazlo así:

```
let newStr : String? = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Y ten cuidado por que la variable es una variable opcional. O sea es de tipo String? no String.

Comment: me retorna `nil` @AlvaroRoyo

Comment: Eso es que tu JSON no está bien formado. @AlbertoMier

Comment: No es un `JSON`, es un NSData(), en concreto un NSData() del body de una peticion http